# Missing callback parameter documentation in Ctrl+Q tooltip

Tags: javascript, phpstorm, phpstorm-2018.1

As shown on the image below, I have specified types for the parameters of callback of the `checkAuth` method but these are not present in `Ctrl+Q`-tooltip. This issue isn't limited to this particular function, it affects all other functions as well. I have flow enabled in PhpStorm.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logged as [WEB-34257](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-34257), please follow it for updates